# Why is getElementById not being recognized?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console-application

I am pasting in the console of a website the following code and I get a valid response.

```
    xhr.open("POST", 'www.website.com', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    xhr.send('value1=242342352&value2=true');

    xhr.onload = function() {
   
    console.log(xhr.responseText);

    var el = document.createElement('html');
    el.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(el.getElementById("id").innerHTML);
    }
```

but I get the following

```
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (<anonymous>:12:16)
    xhr.onload @ VM3313:12
    load (async)
    (anonymous) @ VM3313:6
```

Why does this happen? The object I want is within the response

I cannot use (or edit) the response as I am facing an Unexpected token < in JSON problem.

Comment: I don’t see where the corresponding “Id” is referencing are you dynamically creating it ?

Comment: because `getElementById` is a exclusive method of  `document` and not for any other element

Answer (score 2):

`getElementById` is a **exclusive method of** `document` and not for any other element

use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) insttead

```
console.log(el.querySelector("#id").innerHTML);
```